# Are there any algorithms that would be good at compressing hashes?

Tags: hash, compression

For example, if you have a signed link with a long hash like this:

www.somesite.com/login?s=gsd0fasd90fu09fj34a9wj9fa309jrasdlfkja39a23fsda234dfasdfaf

Are there any reversible compression algorithms that could shorten that to any meaningful degree?

Comment: A hash is (for most purposes) a random string.  Compressing random strings is not much fun.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is right. What you could do is create a lookup table with shorter hashes associated with the long hash, for a period of time. That would not be reversible without access to the lookup table, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is random, you are provably out of luck. Hashes are designed such that no human knows to distinguish them from random. Treat them as random bits.

You can keep a table that maps all the long strings you have seen to shorter ones (maybe integer IDs). That makes sense of the long strings are used many times each. Or, if you want to hand out short strings.

Comment: Even if the input isn't random, the OP is still out of luck, considering the entire point of a hash is to be unpredictable/random to some degree.